# What does "You need to keep your brain at the top of its game" mean?

Tags: idioms

> When you’re on a complex task, keep your brain at the top of its game:
> dump all important stuff on paper.

I don't know what it means (I searched in many different english dictionaries).

Translator can't even translate it into my native language.

Comment: I would recommend understanding what "at top of one's game" stands for first, not sure if you're unclear about that phrase or the fact that it's being used with brain as a subject. The meaning of "brain at top of it's game" is : _To have a sharp/clear mind_ (the sharpest it can get).

Comment: thanks so much!

Comment: Just to be clear, **at the top of one's game** referred originally to athletic sports, not chess or board games.

Comment: I don't find it very idiomatic. The cited example (from a Brazilian programmer, not a native Anglophone) is the only instance of "**brain at the top of its game**" in Google Books (and there's nothing for ***your*** or ***one's*** instead of ***its***). I suggest instead using [*keep you brain **in tip-top condition,***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22brain+in+tip-top+condition%22) which finds hundreds of matches.

Comment: It's not clear in any case how "dumping [sic] all important stuff on paper" keeps the brain at the top of its game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[on top of one's game](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20top%20of%20one%27s%20game) is an idiom:

> variants or **at the top of one's game**
> : doing something at one's highest level

*at the top of its game* in your example is close to the idiom and has similar meaning.

> When you’re on a complex task, keep your brain **functioning at its highest level**...